Building Wheels failed for python - geohash, while installing Apache superset
I am trying to install Apache superset from scratch using in a virtual machine. But it is getting failed at building the wheel for python-geohash.
This is build error I am facing with.
 Building wheel for python-geohash (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      copying geohash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      copying quadtree.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      copying jpgrid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      copying jpiarea.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      running build_ext
      building '_geohash' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABL                                                                             ED=1 -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2                                                                              -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-sw                                                                             itches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection                                                                              -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-s                                                                             ecurity -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-p                                                                             rotector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-                                                                             tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2                                                                              -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_AS                                                                             SERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune                                                                             =generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -                                                                             D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -DPYTHON_MODULE=1 -I/home/cloud-user/superset/v                                                                             env1/include -I/usr/include/python3.8 -c src/geohash.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86                                                                             _64-cpython-38/src/geohash.o
      src/geohash.cpp:538:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       #include <Python.h>
                ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                                                             h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-geohash
  Running setup.py clean for python-geohash
  Building wheel for shortid (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for shortid: filename=shortid-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl size=2598 s                                                                             ha256=b7f869666f7829c06046422811c728aeb47795621367b3a8d9b90aac165f770f
  Stored in directory: /home/cloud-user/.cache/pip/wheels/52/f6/c5/0911db2b5bad6                                                                             2436566f887f3161fffc978e1dadbf75ed6bb
Successfully built apache-superset shortid
Failed to build python-geohash
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-geohash, which is required to install p                                                                             yproject.toml-based projects
(venv1) [cloud-user@EVBLTEMCAPL190 superset]$ deactivate
[cloud-user@EVBLTEMCAPL190 superset]$ git clone <superset repo>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
[cloud-user@EVBLTEMCAPL190 superset]$ dgit clone <superset repo>
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'


I tried going through the web, but any of the mentioned try - outs didn't work out.
And even, I tried installing the python-geohash manually as .tar file and added into my virtual environment directory. Even though it didn't work.

you are missing out python headers.  Typically this called "python-dev" or "python3-dev" ..

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+fatal+error%3A+Python.h%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Thanks for having a look and responding @rasjani, I did install the python headers even though I am facing the same issue.
